# How to emulate the click on a website's button with AppleScript?

Tags: html, google-chrome, automation, applescript

I need to click a specific button on a webpage. The source code of the page related to the button is as follows:

```
<a href="#none" onclick="openViewer('66668', 9);">Animati Workstation</a>
```

Using AppleScript, is there any way I can send this function (emulate the click) without actually clicking on it?

I'm using a MacBook and I intend to create a gesture with the BetterTools App to perform the action: "Run Applescript"

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell active tab of front window
        execute javascript "openViewer('66668', 9);"
    end tell
end tell
```

It's not working. I have managed to open another tab, but couldn't make it click buttons.